# (Python) How to check a long string against several regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to ensure that a long string can match with several regex at once.

I have a long multi line string containing a list of files and some content of the file.

```
DIR1\FILE1.EXT1 CONTENT11
DIR1\FILE1.EXT1 CONTENT12
DIR1\FILE1.EXT1 CONTENT13
DIR1\FILE2.EXT1 CONTENT21
DIR2\FILE3.EXT2 CONTENT31
DIR3\FILE3.EXT2 CONTENT11
```

The list typically contains hundreds of thousands of lines, sometimes several millions.

I want to check that the list contains predefined couples file/content:

```
FILE1 CONTENT11
FILE1 CONTENT12
FILE3 CONTENT11
```

I know that I can check that the string contains all of these couples by matching the string against some regexes

```
"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$"
"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$"
"^\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$"
```

```py
import re

def all_matching(str, rxs):
    res = True
    for rx in rxs:
        p = re.compile(rx, re.M)
        res = res and p.search(str)
    return(res)

input1 = """DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT11
DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT12
DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT13
DIR1\\FILE2.EXT1\tCONTENT21
DIR2\\FILE3.EXT2\tCONTENT31
DIR3\\FILE3.EXT2\tCONTENT11"""

input2 = """DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT11
DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT12
DIR1\\FILE1.EXT1\tCONTENT13
DIR1\\FILE2.EXT1\tCONTENT21
DIR2\\FILE3.EXT2\tCONTENT31"""

rxs = [r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$",r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$",r"^\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$"]

if all_matching(input1,rxs):
    print("input1 matches all rxs") # excpected
else:
    print("input1 do not match all rxs")

if all_matching(input2,rxs):
    print("input2 matches all rxs")
else:
    print("input2 do not match all rxs") # expected because input2 doesn't match wirh rxs[2]
```

[ideone is available here](https://ideone.com/gZdQfU)

However, as the input string is very long in my case, I'd rather avoid launching search many times...
I feel like it should be possible to change the all_matching function in that way.

Any help will be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

clarified the problem an provided sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build a single regex from the regex strings you have that will require all the regexes to find a match in the input string.

The resulting regex will look like

```
\A(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$)(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$)(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gATLg/3).

Basically, it will match:

- `(?m)` - a `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` embedded flag option
- `\A` - start of string (not start of a line!), all the lookaheads below will be triggered one by one, checking the string from the start, until one of them fails
- `(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires the presence of

  - `(?:.*\n)*?` - 0 or more (but as few as possible, the pattern will only be tried if the subsequent subpatterns do not match)
  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespaces
  - `FILE1` - a string
  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespaces
  - `\tCONTENT11` - tab and `CONTENT11` substring
  - `$` - end of line (since `(?m)` allows `$` to match end of lines)
- `(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$)` - a lookahead working similarly as the preceding one, requiring `FILE1` and `CONTENT12` substrings on the line
- `(?=(?:.*\n)*?\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$)` - a lookahead working similarly as the preceding one, requiring `FILE3` and `CONTENT11` substrings on the line.

In Python, it will look like

```
rxs = [r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$",r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$",r"^\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$"]
pat = re.compile( r"(?m)\A(?=(?:.*\n)*?{})".format(r")(?=(?:.*\n)*?".join([rx[1:] for rx in rxs])) )
```

Then, the check method will look like

```
def all_matching(s, pat):
    return pat.search(s)
```

See [full Python demo online](https://ideone.com/l5QZGB).

Comment: I edited the question.
My question is not how to factorize the regex. It's : how can you check a text agains several regex at once ?

Comment: @wkirschenmann See https://ideone.com/4P0csU, do you mean this?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Still wrong problem.
I probably haven't been clear. I tried to describe my problem with some code here : https://ideone.com/gZdQfU The issue, il that in reality, my input is very long (millions of lines) and I'd like to avoid running the search several times.

Comment: @wkirschenmann Is it the solution? Sorry, I do not quite get it, there is just code. you have  a multiline string input, ok, but please make it a minimal example. So, you have `input1` var with lots of lines and you have `rxs = [r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11$",r"^\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT12$",r"^\S*FILE3\S*\tCONTENT11$"]`, do you just want to get `True` as a result if all lines match all the patterns in `rgx`?

Comment: It is *a* solution but I think not a good one as I need to iterate over rxs and so I have to go through input several times.

I want to get True as a result if all patterns are matched (any line, I don't care).

Comment: @wkirschenmann I could come up with a [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/8gATLg/1), see [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oIhv78). Not that efficient, I am afraid.

Comment: Exactly that !
Thanks. Do you know how the regex works under the hood ? Does it loop several times over the input ?

Comment: @wkirschenmann The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/8gATLg/1) will check if it is at the start of the string (with `\A`), then will try to match `\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11` pattern, and if it fails, it will grab the first char, and again will try to match `\S*FILE1\S*\tCONTENT11`, etc. After failing to get a match for the first lookahead, it will stop parsing the string. But  if the first lookahead finds the match and the last one fail, it might still take some processing time. Well, I could make the regex more efficient.

Comment: I must admit that regex have always seemed like magic tricks to me.
Your current solution is still better than one quggestedby one colleage : each FILE/CONTENT appears only on so looking for any of them (as you proposed in your first answer) and counting the number of matches gives the answer.

Comment: If you know how to make the regex more efficient, it'd be appreciated. Anyhow, if you could edit you main answer, I'll mark it as the answer.